# NameError: name 'Label' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

При попытке запуска приложения вылезает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "wd.py", line 4, in <module>
lbl = Label(root, text="Hello")
NameError: name 'Label' is not defined
```

Вот код:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text="Hello")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

btn = Button(root)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Label` и `Button` находятся в `tk` поэтому надо писать `tk.Label` и `tk.Button`:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Hello")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

btn = tk.Button(root)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

либо импортировать все и место `tk.Tk` писать `Tk`:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text="Hello")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

btn = Button(root)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!